# Django DateField validators are not running

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, datefield

I have a DateField as part of a form.

```
    date = forms.DateField(
        required=True,
        input_formats=[DATE_INPUT_FORMATS]
    )
```

When I view the form, on the front end, and I enter garbage in to the date field, Django doesn't throw a forms.ValidationError, and instead proceeds to execute the forms clean() method.

I have tried adding my own custom validation method to the DateField:

```
    def validate_date_field(dateval):
        raise forms.ValidationError("date error...")

    date = forms.DateField(
        required=True,
        input_formats=[DATE_INPUT_FORMATS],
        validators=[validate_date_field]
    )
```

Even when my validate_date_field function is set up to always return a validation error, it does not execute. Instead, and again, Django proceeds to execute the code in the forms clean() method...

What's going on ?

Comment: Is your issue that you did not expect your custom `Form.clean` method to be called if any field fails it's validation?

Comment: Yes, I was under the impression that form_clean() would only be called if all validation / field_clean() methods before it were successful...

Comment: perhaps I need to manually check if self.is_valid(), at the beginning of form_clean() ?

Comment: You should check if `date` is in `cleaned_data` in your clean method, if it's not then it failed validation